# Format String For Total Hours of Timespan

Tags: asp.net

I am using TimeSpan in a Telerik Grid. In the dataformat of the column I want only the total_hours of data in each row. What fromat_string I should use there? For example if I would need hours and minutes, I would use "hh:mm"! but for total hours?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is a default format to get the hours. I think you must be able to define some custom format.(I am not sure though !)

If you don't want to define some custom format, you can do this:
Assume your grid is bound to some **ViewModel** object which is having **Datetime** as one of its property. You can define one more property called **NoOfHours**. In the getter of this property, you can actually return the number of hours from the Datetime property. You can then bind the column of the grid to **NoOfHours** property. 
Then you need not use any formatting. Hope it helps you !